# How to Click on button under i frame in cypress

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

I am trying to click on the iframe button. but I am not able to do this in cypress.

[image: Below is the button code and I want to click on this to complete registration flow]

Please help me to do in this Cypress

Comment: I recommend reading this article https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/. And you have no button anywhere on the screen, it looks like a link.